# Trying to access array offset on value of type null Prestashop 1.7.8.8 PHP 7.4

Tags: php, arrays, prestashop-1.7

I have this error in my prestashop backoffice
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLS1w.png)

This is the code:

```
<?php ob_start();
echo $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['tag']->value['id_carrier'];
$_prefixVariable6 = ob_get_clean();
if($_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['carriersAssociation']->value[$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['tagCarrierMip']->value['id']] == $_prefixVariable6) {
    ?>selected<?php 
    }?>> <?php echo $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['tag']->value['name'];?>
</option>
```

The error its in the "if" line, I think that some processes are not working properly due to this error.

Any words about how could I avoid this error?

I have tried to enter "isset" according to some posts that I have seen but no changes at all.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to debug your code to figure out where this `null` is... There's a lot of places that could be `null` in your code, but your error is saying "access array offset", which is `[...]`. So `$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars`, or `$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['carriersAssociation']->value`, or `$_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['tagCarrierMip']->value`, etc. `null[...]` is not valid PHP syntax, and that is what at least one part of your code is compiling to, based on your error.

Comment: Why are you using the ob_XXX functions just to set a variable? Use `$_prefixVariable6 = $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['tag']->value['id_carrier'];`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.